# Une nuance entre « être » et « faire »

Tags: usage, verbes

In the first two examples, you can use both "être" and "faire", but do native speakers detect nuances of meaning?

1st Example:

> Quel fouineur vous **êtes** !
>
> Quel fouineur vous **faites** !

2nd Example:

> C'**est** la deuxième fois que tu me répètes la même chose.
>
> Ça/Cela **fait** la deuxième fois que tu me répètes la même chose.

In the following example, on the other hand, I assume that only "faire" can be used. But I’m not sure why exactly.

3rd Example:

> Ça/Cela **fait** je ne sais combien de fois que tu me répètes la même chose.

Comment: On the first one, we are already known as a "fouineur" with "être" (don't know how to say it in English), while with "faire", we acted like one. I don't see a difference on the second example, maybe that "faire" we insist on the fact that's it's the second time, but we can't accentuate in oral two on "deuxième". On the third one, I don't think it's replaceable.

Comment: @Larme For the third, I suppose it could be replaced by the more informal: "C'est la je-ne-sais-combien-t-ième fois que tu me répètes la même chose"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1er exemple**

> Vous faites = Vous avez l'air de, vous ressemblez à (avec une certaine
>   ironie).

**2ème exemple**

On dit plus simplement:

> Cela fait deux fois, trois fois.

totalement équivalent à:

> C'est la deuxième fois, la troisième fois, ...

*Cela fait* est suivi d'un COD, et peut être suivi de beaucoup d'expressions, de temps, d'occurence = **3ème exemple**.

> Cela fait plein de fois, cela fait trop de fois, cela fait 3 ans, cela
>   fait des années, cela fait une éternité.

Answer (score 1):

*Être* is meant to be precise, where *faire* indicates roughly the amount.

> Ca va faire la quizième fois que je me réveille cette nuit

Means the person woke up once, then once again, then again, they counted and it adds up to about 15 times. It's often an estimation as it's used when the number is large enough for you to lose track, or when you just couldn't keep track.

In your second example, 2 a bit small though, personally I'd start using *fait* after a few more times. It's not wrong but *être* would be better here.

The last example illustrates that perfectly : the *je ne sais combien* means you have lost track of how many times.

Note that the word *faire* is used as the "=" for sums :

> Deux plus deux, ça fait quatre
>
> Deux et deux font quatre

(*Two plus two is four*, if I'm not mistaken)

The first example is something different completely. The fact that *faire* can also be substituted with *être* is a coincidence. It's a relatively isolated, you should be fine by learning just that phrase (If you find a counter-example feel free to edit and I'll edit my answer).